# ViewHolder click is messing other views

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-viewholder

I have the following **RecyclerView.Adapter**:

```
class SpeciesAdapter(val activity: Activity, private val species: ArrayList<Specie>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpeciesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.specie_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val specie = species[position]
        holder.specie.text = specie.name
        holder.header.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.information.visibility == View.GONE) showInformation(holder)
            else hideInformation(holder)
        }
    }

    private fun showInformation(holder: ViewHolder) {
        holder.information.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.arrow.rotation = -90f
    }

    private fun hideInformation(holder: ViewHolder) {
        holder.information.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.arrow.rotation = 90f
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = species.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val header: RelativeLayout = view.header_layout
        val arrow: ImageView = view.arrow_image
        val specie: TextView = view.specie_text
        val information: LinearLayout = view.information_layout
    }
}
```

And is producing this:

https://media.giphy.com/media/9JcLhfgXOdt81WUxsE/giphy.mp4

As you can notice, if I click an item, a layout with a loading is opened. My problem is that when I click an item and then scroll, some other items are opened as well, but I did not click them. Is like the **ViewHolder** is recycling the view and doesn't care that the layout with the loading bar should be invisible.

What could be wrong in my adapter?

Comment: obviously you are not reseting view state in onBindViewHolder

Comment: How should I reset the state?

Comment: by calling hideInformation ?

Comment: may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861878/android-view-setactive-setselected-and-recyclerview-states/48862189#48862189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you have to understand is that a ViewHolder is a View that can represent any Specie object at a given time. This ViewHolder is reused by the RecyclerView and bound to other Specie objects when there is some scroll, trying to have the minimum amount of Views loaded (that's why it is called "Recycler").

If you just change a property of a holder for a Specie item, when the holder is reused to show another Specie object, the property remain the same if you don't "reset" it.

In short, you have to set all ViewHolder properties within the bind method to ensure that the holder is now properly representing the Specie object that is going to show.

That said, what you have to do, for example, is to keep a list or map or what you want to know what Specie object is "expanded" at a given time, and when the bind method is called, check if that specific Specie object must be expanded or not and show the holder extended information based on it.

---

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION FOR QUESTION:**

```
class SpeciesAdapter(val activity: Activity, private val species: ArrayList<Specie>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpeciesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    // added an ArrayList to store the opened species
    private val opened = arrayListOf<Specie>()

    // ...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val specie = species[position]

        // added a condition to check if a specie was opened
        // and updates according to the result
        if (opened.contains(specie)) showInformation(holder, specie)
        else hideInformation(holder, specie)

        holder.specie.text = specie.name
        holder.header.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.information.visibility == View.GONE) showInformation(holder, specie)
            else hideInformation(holder, specie)
        }
    }

    private fun showInformation(holder: ViewHolder, specie: Specie) {
        holder.information.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.arrow.rotation = -90f

        // checking if is opened to avoid duplicates
        if (!opened.contains(specie)) opened.add(specie)
    }

    private fun hideInformation(holder: ViewHolder, specie: Specie) {
        holder.information.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.arrow.rotation = 90f

        // checking if exists to avoid crashes
        if (opened.contains(specie)) opened.remove(specie)
    }

    // ...
}
```